# PFRelation Query doesn't return object

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a PFObject, Object1 with a PFRelation to another object Object2.  When I query for all Object1's and as I iterate through the array, I try to get the query for the PFRelation to Object2 in order to pull down that object.  The issue I'm having is that the result of that query from the PFRelation is always empty.

```
PFQuery *relationQuery = [PFObject1.childRelationship query];
[relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"I'm empty);
}];
```

If I go into the Parse console, I can clearly see the relationship is intact between Object1 and Object2. I can click on the relationship on Object1, and it will take me to the right Object2.

Regardless it's always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of assuming that relations between objects in parse were of the type PFRelation when in reality it is only a PFReleation if it is a many to many relationship, otherwise it's a pointer to the other class.  I changed the code to "fetchIfNeeded" on the pointer to pull my object and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam I also made the Pointer/PFRelation mistake originally - I should have read the documentation more closely! If you need the related object every time this might be easier/cleaner. Here's how to do it per the Parse documentation. The `includeKey` is the essential part. Hope that's useful

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];

// Retrieve the most recent ones
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

// Only retrieve the last ten
query.limit = 10;

// Include the post data with each comment
[query includeKey:@"post"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
  // Comments now contains the last ten comments, and the "post" field
  // has been populated. For example:
  for (PFObject *comment in comments) {
     // This does not require a network access.
     PFObject *post = comment[@"post"];
     NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@", post);
  }
}];
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS